# gulp copying from source to destination is not working

Tags: gulp

```
    var gulp=require('gulp'),
        gutil=require('gulp-util');
    gulp.task('default',function(){

    gulp.src('G:\node\node_modules\npm\test\gulpfile.js').pipe(gulp.dest('G:\node\node_modules\npm\test\sample'));
         return gutil.log("inside");
        });
```

i'm a beginner to gulp.js . i have tried to cpoy a file from a source loaction to a destination location. It doesn't show any errors. But the file is not copied in destination location. I tried even different locations but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
   return gulp.src('./gulpfile.js')
              .pipe(gulp.dest('./sample/');
});
```